# Skip "Installing function extensions if needed"

Tags: maven, azure-functions, azure-java-tools

I use the [`maven-plugin-for-azure-functions`](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/tree/develop/azure-functions-maven-plugin#maven-plugin-for-azure-functions) to create a Java Function App with a custom Trigger Binding. The custom trigger is created by another .Net project and publishs its artifacts via an Azure Devops Artifacts feed as an universal package.

I consume the custom trigger as universal package to get rid of the .Net dependencies during my Java Function App build.

While I download the package and copy its content into the `stagingDirectory`, the `maven-plugin-for-azure-functions` tries to install some extensions, too.

```
[INFO] Step 8 of 8: Installing function extensions if needed
...
[INFO] Function extension installation done.
```

The step creates a `extensions.csproj` with some default extensions and overrides the files of my custom extension. I tried to remove the `PackageReference` elements, but it's reverted with every `package` run.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <WarningsAsErrors></WarningsAsErrors>
    <DefaultItemExcludes>**</DefaultItemExcludes>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventGrid" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator" Version="1.1.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

How can I disable the *function extensions installation*?

Comment: I created a feature request, see [Provide property to skip extensions installation](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/issues/1616).

Answer (score 3):

In `pom.xml` add `skipInstallExtensions` to avoid run step in `mvn package`. Check example below:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-functions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.13.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <configuration>
        <!-- potential configuration property -->
        <skipInstallExtensions>true</skipInstallExtensions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found some workaround for the implicit extension installation of the plugin.

1. During the `prepare-package` phase, I replace the `host.json` with some dummy file, which suppresses the installation process.

   ```json
   {
     "version": "2.0",
     "extensionBundle": {
       "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
       "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
     }
   }
   ```

   Therefore the plugin skips the extension installation.

   ```
   [INFO] Step 8 of 8: Installing function extensions if needed
   [INFO] Extension bundle specified, skip install extension
   [INFO] Successfully built Azure Functions.
   ```
2. I moved the script for the universal package download to the `package` phase, which is executed after the plugin. The script also reverts the `host.json` by removing the `extensionBundle` property and copies the reverted file to the `stagingDirectory`.

The resulting archive contains the `bin` folder of the universal package finally with the correct `host.json`.